# How to fix space leak caused by laziness when your algorithm relies on laziness

Tags: performance, haskell

I have some algorithm which generates a search tree:

```
data SearchTree a = Solution a | Contradiction | Search [ SearchTree a ]
  deriving (Show, Functor)
```

The algorithm generates this tree lazily. I also defined a simple evaluator, which is really just depth first search.

```
simpleEval :: MonadPlus m => SearchTree a -> m a
simpleEval (Solution a) = return a 
simpleEval Contradiction = mzero 
simpleEval (Search ps) = foldr mplus mzero $ map simpleEval ps
```

I noticed that many of the solutions that my algorithm produces look something like the following search tree:

```
nest :: Int -> SearchTree a -> SearchTree a 
nest 0 = id 
nest n = nest (n-1) . Search . (:[]) 

tree0 = Search ts where 
  ts = cycle $ t0 : replicate 100 t1 ++ [t2]
  t0 = nest 100 $ Solution 'a' 
  t1 = nest 1000 $ Contradiction 
  t2 = nest 4 $ Solution 'b'
```

Namely, they have a lot of very deep branches with no solutions, a few deep branches with a solution, and very few shallow branches with a solution. On this basis, I decided I wanted another evaluator, one which will 'give up' on branches that are too deep. Call it `cutoffEval`. `cutoffEval 5 tree0` should find only `b`s because it there are infinitely many branches of depth less than 5 to consider, and they only contain `b`s. I implemented it like so:

```
cutoff :: (MonadPlus m) => Int -> SearchTree a -> (m a, [SearchTree a])
cutoff cu = go cu where 
  plus ~(m0, l0) ~(m1, l1) = (mplus m0 m1, l0 ++ l1)
  zero = (mzero, [])

  go 0 x             = (mzero, [x])
  go _ Contradiction = zero
  go _ (Solution a)  = (return a, [])
  go d (Search ps)   = foldr plus zero $ map (go $ d-1) ps

cutoffEval :: MonadPlus m => Int -> SearchTree a -> m a
cutoffEval cu = go where 
  go t = case cutoff cu t of (r,ts) -> foldr mplus mzero $ r : map go ts
```

But this function produces a huge space leak, as compared to `simpleEval`:

```
putStrLn $ take 4000 $ simpleEval tree0  -- 2MB residency
putStrLn $ take 4000 $ cutoffEval 10 tree0  -- 600MB residency
```

Profiling reveals that almost all allocation occurs in `cutoff.go`; and the majority of allocation is due something mysterious called `main:Tree.sat_s5jg` and the `(,)` constructor. This seems to me due to the irrefutable patterns, the tuple constructors are being built up as thunks instead of being forced by `plus`; and normally the solution to a space leak is to make your function stricter, but here removing the irrefutable patterns causes `cutoff` to hang, so I cannot do it.

I tested this with GHC 7.6, 7.8 and 7.10. The problem was found in each one.

So my questions are: Can `cutoffEval` be written to run in constant space like `simpleEval`? And more generally, how do I fix a space leak, if I can't make my implementation stricter because the algorithm depends on it?

Comment: I [can't](http://ideone.com/hQu1ut) reproduce. Are you compiling with `-O2`? You can make `go` safely stricter by removing only the first irrefutable pattern in `plus`, thus saying "I need `seq`, but not `deepseq`". BTW, `foldr mplus mzero` is `msum`.

Comment: @user3237465 I am compiling with optimizations. I can reproduce the problem with exactly the module you linked. Removing only the first irrefutable pattern has no effect. What version of ghc are you using? Perhaps I should include the results of profiling on my machine in the question.

Comment: @user2407038 what ghc versions are *you* using. When you post a question *you* should make sure that other people can reproduce the results and thus find a solution. So it's *your* version of ghc that is important in order to answer your question.

Comment: The version with a space leak runs in `188` MB with my configuration (GHC version 7.8.3). Changing `plus` to `plus (m0, !l0) ~(m1, l1) = (mplus m0 m1, l0 ++ l1)` results in `75` MB. After forcing the entire `l0` in `plus`, I get `34` MB, but that doesn't work for trees with childs that have infinite number of childs.

Comment: @Bakuriu I tested on several versions, because I had run into issues before where a certain version of GHC had some performance issue in some edge cases. The problem was found on every version I tested, so I didn't feel it would be relevant. Anyways, I'll include those versions in the question.

Comment: @user3237465 It seems there are actually two spaces leaks. One due to the irrefutable pattern on the first tuple. The other due to the list being too lazy... perhaps a different data structure is needed?

Comment: @user3237465 It seems that `++` is part of the problem.. it requires the entire first list to be traversed, which never happens for infinite lists. Replacing `l0 ++ l1` with `fairMerge l0 l1`, ([fairMerge](https://gist.github.com/yuriy0/69064a8b549e0b50b3e2)) reduces residency on my machine by a factor of 10, from 300MB to 30MB! This still isn't perfect (30MB >> 2MB)  but still a step in the right direction. Thank you for the help.

Comment: For `tree0` `l0` is always finite: the version with `plus (m0, l0) ~(m1, l1) | seq (foldl const () l0) True = (mplus m0 m1, l0 ++ l1)` runs in `18` MB on my machine. As well as the version with `fairMerge` and a bang pattern before `l0`. The version with `fairMerge` consumes less memory, because `fairMerge` forces both lists, not just the first as `(++)`: `(+++)` works equally well (`xs +++ [] = xs; [] +++ ys = ys; (x:xs) +++ ys = x : (xs +++ ys)`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the reason for the memory leak is actually a bug in the implementation. Your `cutoff` function mixes together cutting off too deep branches with evaluating the upper part. And then in `cutoffEval`, you go deeper to the bottom, cut branches, and continue to explore them recursively. Which is essentially breadth-first search, going by `cu` levels in each pass. This means that the whole tree will eventually be constructed and retained in memory until the end! (Unlike the case of a depth-first search, where visited subtrees can be reclaimed by the GC.)

If you want to just cut off the branches that are too deep, getting the first part of the result of `cutoff` is what you want.

In any case I'd suggest to separate the evaluator and the cut-off part (see below). In such a case you can just use the original evaluator on the cut-off version of the tree.

One additional remark, from the `MonadPlus` constraint you use just the monoidal part - `mzero` and `mplus`. It'd be cleaner and more generic to use just `Monoid`. There are more monoids than monads (for example `Sum` to just count solutoins, or `Last` to find the last solution).

```
simpleEval :: (Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> SearchTree a -> m
simpleEval f = go
  where
    go (Solution a) = f a
    go Contradiction = mempty
    go (Search ps) = mconcat $ map go ps 

cutoff :: Int -> SearchTree a -> SearchTree a
cutoff cu = go cu
  where 
    go 0 _             = Contradiction -- too deep branches are just failures
    go d (Search ps)   = Search $ map (go (d - 1)) ps
    go _ x             = x

cutoffEval :: (Monoid m) => Int -> (a -> m) -> SearchTree a -> m
cutoffEval cu f = simpleEval f . cutoff cu
```

Comment: "If you want to just cut off the branches that are too deep" - I don't, this is a different function altogether which would not suit my needs. Your earlier statement "Which is essentially breadth-first search, going by cu levels in each pass" was correct - this is exactly what I want. Also, I used `MonadPlus` because I use `return`.

Comment: @user2407038 I see, so you don't want to cut off the branches that are too deep, you just want to traverse them later. I'll have another look then. Is there a particular reason why you want to do this leveled approach, and not just plain breadth-first search, which would be simpler?

Comment: @user2407038 You don't need to use `return`, it's role is replaced by `a -> m` for a monoid `m`. You could simplify even more, as your structure is a functor, you could only concentrate to cases where your structure containd monoid elements `(Monoid m) => SearchTree m -> ...` and use `fmap` before evaluating it. It's just as [`fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) and [`fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold). For folding, `Monoid` is enough, for traversing, `Applicative` is enough.

Comment: @Petr Pudlák, [the leveled approach](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/Searches.hs) can be much more efficient, if you turn off memoization. I guess, combining `iter_deepening` with DFS can give you the best of  two worlds.